# How to extract element using .find of jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, find

I'm having such stuff

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sht #3</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div style="-moz-transform-origin: bottom left;">

Begin PDF
<br />
      <embed type="application/pdf" id="pdf" src="plugin-lshort.pdf" style="width:300px;height:400px;" />
<br />
End PDF

</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

I've used jQuery.find like this

```
$(document).find("[nodeName!='EMBED']")
```

OK. It can return 2 elements BR

But when I try to extract the EMBED element by:

```
$(document).find("[nodeName='EMBED']")
```

or

```
$(document).find("[nodeName=='EMBED']")
```

It was unable to return my expected EMBED element.

Anyone kind please help me ?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to get the embed element with

```
$(document).find('embed')
```

or more concisely, just

```
$('embed')
```

This works because you're searching for a tag name. It's no different than searching for $('a') or $('div')

Answer (score 1):

Just do this :

```
$('embed')
```

It will return all the embed elements.

You can do a lot of stuff with this : http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2010/05/a-complete-guide-to-jquery-1-4-selector-expressions/ Have a look there for more information